# Add the numbers in a columns into another using buttons in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am learning to code VBA/Macros in excel and I have reached am stuck at one point. I could use your help. So I have two columns A and B . I have created a ActiveX button named ADD. What I am trying to do is every time I click ADD, I want to add the values of Column A and B into B. For Example:

```
    Column A            Column B
1    1                      2
2    1                      3
3    2                      4
4    4                      5
5    3                      5
```

Once I press ADD, I would like to have column B be updated with the value of Column A + Column B, like

```
    Column A            Column B
1    1                      3
2    1                      4
3    2                      6
4    4                      9
5    3                      8
```

I tried something like this :

```
Private Sub ADD_Click()

 Sheets("Sheet1").Range(B1:B5).Select
 activecell.Formula= "=SUM([@columnA],[@columnB])

End Sub
```

I keep getting run time error 1004.

Is there a way to do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

### Sum Up the Values of Two Columns in One of Those Columns

```vb
Private Sub ADD_Click()

   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B5")
       .Value = .Worksheet.Evaluate(.Offset(, -1).Address & "+" & .Address)
   End With

End Sub
```